# If $f$ is analytic and $3\operatorname{Re}f+2\operatorname{Im}f$ is constant, is $f$ also constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon U\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic on a region $U$. If $f=u+iv$ and $3u+2v=c\in\mathbb{R}$ is constant, is it true that $f$ is also constant?

Comment: The open mapping theorem is your friend.